# Access to HTML Button in aspx.cs (Code Behind)

Tags: asp.net, html, code-behind

I have a doubt: if I write a `HTML button` in source code, how can I access it in the `aspx.cs`,
Can you provide me some examples?

Answer (score 5):

If you set an ID on the button and set the `runat` attribute to `server` you'll able to get it from code-behind with `FindControl`.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton" runat="server" />
```

Code-behind (C#):

```
Button myButton = (Button) FindControl("myButton");
```

Also, instead of using html you can use the defined ASP-tag for buttons...

```
<asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" />
```

Now you have the help of auto-completion etc. in the code-behind:

```
myButton.Text = "My Button";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add the `runat="server"` and `id="mybutton"` attributes to the button then you can access it in your code via the generated `myButton` variable.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want to use component ASP:XXX, you can use HTML Controls see below:
HTML

```
<button  ID="cmdbutton" runat="server" class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode btn btn-default btn-lg right" type="button">Sua boleta já está disponível</button>
```

See, I used runat="server"in HTML control.
Code-behind(VB.NET)

```
Dim vloControl As System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton
vloControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("cmdButton"),System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlButton)
vloControl.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "CallFunJs();")
```

Comment: how can we do this for C#? in my case, I'm not from click event, but instead when page_load event. many thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can access it by giving it an `ID` and adding the `runat="server"` attribute to the html button element.

You can then access it like any other server control, using the ID that you set.